# Python - remove a word or matching string from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to remove a word from a text file and found a code that seems to be working.

However, it doesn't match an exact word, instead removes all matching letters.

```
fin = open("input.txt")
fout = open("output.txt", "w+")
delete_list = input('delete : ')
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, '')
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
print ('done')
```

input.txt

```
http://www.google.co.ma
google.com.mm
https://google.mn
www.google.com.mt
```

Result for trying to remove http:// (only) is as following-

output.txt

```
www.google.co.ma
google.com.mm
sgoogle.mn
www.google.com.m
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what's happening here:

1. You call `input`, which returns a string, "http://". You assign this to the variable `delete_list`.
2. You loop through `delete_list` using a `for` loop. But note: `delete_list` is a string, not a list. When you use a `for` loop to iterate through a string, it loops through the *letters* of the string.
3. You go through each letter and remove it from the line.

There are three things you could do to fix this:

1. Change your assignment of `delete_list` to assign to a single-element list: `delete_list = [input("word to delete: ")]`
2. Rename `delete_list` to more accurately reflect its true value, something like `word_to_delete`, then don't use a `for` loop -- just do `line.replace(word_to_delete, '')` directly.
3. Use a loop to get a *list* of words from the user.

Hope that clears things up!

Answer (score 1):

I just started coding so don't know how ugly is this solution looks, but **re** module seems fine.

```
from re import sub
with open('test.txt') as f:
    file = f.read().split('\n')
for i in range(len(file)):
    file[i] = sub(r'http[s]?://', '', file[i])
#print(file)
with open('test1.txt', 'w') as f1:
    f1.writelines(["%s\n" % item  for item in file])
```

or if you don't want to use **re** module, you can use **if** statement instead

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    file = f.read().split('\n')
for i in range(len(file)):
    if file[i].startswith('https://'):
        link = file[i]
        file[i] = link[8:]
    elif file[i].startswith('http://'):
        link = file[i]
        file[i] = link[7:]
#print(file)
with open('test1.txt', 'w') as f1:
    f1.writelines(["%s\n" % item  for item in file])
```